# How do I make git show diff when rewording a commit message during rebase -i?

Tags: git, rebase

I always use `git commit --verbose`. Is there an equivalent option/setting that will make git show me the diff when I'm rewording a commit message during `git rebase --interactive`?

Comment: I don’t think so. How about doing it yourself in the editor, e.g. in vi `:r !git diff HEAD^` or similar?

Comment: @chirlu ooh yeah, that's a handy workaround, thank you.

Comment: @AdamMonsen, how do you "reword a commit message during git rebase --interactive"? Do you do it in the initial screen, replacing "pick" by "reword" and giving the new message directly, or do you replace "pick" by "edit" and use "git commit --amend" to change the commit message?

Comment: @Vampire, good question. I'm talking about the former: changing "pick" to "reword". But simply using "edit" sounds like another great workaround! There may be some other differences between "reword" and "edit" (besides the obvious user-visible ones), I don't know.

Comment: Related: [Show diff when writing commit messages during an interactive rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47988748/5916915)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to your answers in the comments, executing `git diff HEAD^` will not help you, except if you only want to reword the last commit.

But in this case a rebase is the wrong tool anyway. Instead you can simply do `git commit --amend --verbose` without changes in the index and then edit the commit message, having the diff view you are asking for.

If you want to reword an older or multiple commit messages with having the diff view, just use the `edit` stanza instead of the `reword` stanza and then use `git commit --amend --verbose` without code changes in the index on each of the commits.

`reword` should only be a shortcut for using `edit` and then do `git commit --amend -m "new message"` without any changes which will only change the commit message.

You can also define `git commit --amend --verbose` or `git commit --verbose` as alias so you save some typing and can e.g. simply do `git cav` or `git c --amend`.

Comment: Instead of using the `edit` command in an interactive rebase which will drop you to the shell where have to type `git commit --amend --verbose` to edit the commit and then `git rebase --continue` you can simply add a line after the respective commit with `exec git commit --amend --verbose`. This will drop you directly into the editor for that commit and continue the rebase after you exit the editor.

Comment: Ah nice, somehow didn't ever consider `exec` stanza.

Answer (score 9):

To show the diff:

```
git -c commit.verbose=true rebase --interactive
```

To make all commits verbose without having to specify `-c commit.verbose=true` every time, add this to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[commit]
    verbose = true
```

Reference: [`man git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitverbose).