# Show diff when writing commit messages during an interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

When doing a regular git commit, `git commit --verbose` shows the diff in the text editor when writing the commit message.

Suppose I am doing an interactive rebase (`git rebase --interactive`) to edit previous commits. To 'continue' rebasing, I run `git rebase --continue`. This opens a text editor for editing the commit message, but it does not show the diff. After making changes to a commit, how can I display the diff when (re)writing the commit message during an interactive rebase?

`git rebase --continue --verbose` doesn't seem like a valid command...

Comment: When does `git  rebase --continue` open a text editor?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk After selecting commits to edit during an interactive rebase, and after `git add` to mark the changes, `git rebase --continue` opens a text editor.

Comment: hmm, ok, I think I got. See my answer.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721183/how-do-i-make-git-show-diff-when-rewording-a-commit-message-during-rebase-i

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To show the diff:

```
git -c commit.verbose=true rebase --continue
```

To make all commits verbose without having to specify `-c commit.verbose=true` every time, add this to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[commit]
    verbose = true
```

Reference: [`man git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitverbose).

Comment: To enable verbose commits for the current user from the command line, execute `git config --global commit.verbose true`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
git -c commit.verbose=true rebase --continue
```

If you get tired copying that command you can create an
alias in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    myrebasecontinue = "!git -c commit.verbose=true rebase --continue"
```

And now just do:

```
git myrebasecontinue
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to show the diff. Does it matter that I'm using git 2.7.4?

Comment: Yes, a quick look at `git` source shows that `commit.verbose` was introduced in `git 2.9`

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of a rebase,

```
git diff
```

shows you the changes not yet added to the commit,

```
git diff --cached
```

shows you the new changes you committed, and

```
git show
```

shows you the original changes in the commit you're editting.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. What I'm asking for is to show the diff within the text editor (similar to that shown for `git commit --verbose`).

Comment: @Flux, I do `:r !git diff` in Vim, no idea whether there's something in Git itself to do this automatically. I'm afraid, there isn't.

Comment: You can always write a script that runs the git commands, captures the output to a temp file, opens it in your editor (in the background), and runs `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was googling for! Nice